# my index.JS file show raw source code instead of showing the output in every browser

Tags: javascript, if-statement, browser, console.log

[This is my JS file and this is my code in text editor(VS CODE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvLkY.png)

[and this is what it is showing in OPERA browser and almost in every browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHaUx.png)

I want the output but it is showing the raw code..!
this all happened after I installed node.js in my pc, I installed node.js because I want my JS code to show output in terminal that's all I know about Node JS, but now I had successfully uninstalled node from  my pc but the same problem exists. Before installing node in pc my JS code show complete output without such problem.

Comment: Loading a JS file into the browser doesn't execute it. You need to load an HTML file that contains a `<script>` tag that loads it.

Comment: To run a script in node.js, use `node index.js` from a terminal, you don't use a browser.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're trying to run a Node application.

To run this script make sure you have Node installed then run `node <fileName>.js` in your terminal to see your output.